# Magento SOAP API sales_order_shipment create and addTrack questions

Tags: php, magento, soap, magento-1.7, magento-1.5

Some former programmers wrote this program using the Magento SOAP API V1 to mark shipped orders as shipped. On the former Magento vs 1.5 platform it worked okay but now on vs 1.7 the tracking numbers themselves are not being imported. As you can see half way down I have my name commented out //Caitlin. The line above that is what the former programmers put, and the two lines after that are what I think the code is supposed to be for Magento vs 1.7, but I last time I tried this snippet I put a halt in their operations. Does this look correct to you? Any ideas?

```
   $comment = '<b><br>*** Order has shipped. ***</b><br/><br/>' . 
                           '<b>3PL order number:</b> ' .  $fields[1] . '<br/>' . 
                           '<b>Weight:</b> ' .  $fields[2] . '<br/>' . 
                           '<b>Shipped via:</b> ' .  $fields[3] . '<br/>' . 
                           '<b>Tracking number:</b> ' .  $fields[4] . '<br/>' . 
                           '<b>Ship date:</b> ' .  $fields[5] . '<br/>' . 
                           '<b>Postage:</b> ' .  $fields[6] . '<br/>' . 
                           '<b>Fulfillment:</b> ' .  $fields[7] . '<br/>' . 
                           '<b>Per packslip:</b> ' .  $fields[8];

            // Make shipment and add tracking number
            if ($fields[3] == 'UPS-RESIDENTIAL') { $shippedby = 'ups'; $shipname = 'UPS Ground'; }
            elseif ($fields[3] == 'UPS-2') { $shippedby = 'ups'; $shipname = 'UPS 2nd Day Air'; }
            elseif ($fields[3] == 'UPS-OVERNIGHT') { $shippedby = 'ups'; $shipname = 'UPS Next Day Air Saver'; }
            elseif ($fields[3] == 'USPS-PRI') { $shippedby = 'usps'; $shipname = 'USPS Priority'; }
            elseif ($fields[3] == 'CANADA') { $shippedby = 'custom'; $shipname = 'MSI Canada (Standard) '; }
            elseif ($fields[3] == 'MSITRACK') { $shippedby = 'custom'; $shipname = 'MSI Canada (Express)'; }
            else { $shippedby = 'custom'; }
            // Attempt to create the order, notify on failure
            try { 
            $newShipmentId = $client->call($sess_id, 'sales_order_shipment.create', array($ShippedOrderId, array(), $comment, true, false, $shippedby, $shipname, $fields[4]));

            //Caitlin
            //$newShipmentId = $client->call($sess_id, 'sales_order_shipment.create', array($ShippedOrderId, array(), $comment, true, false)); 
            //$newTrackId = $proxy->call($sessionId, 'sales_order_shipment.addTrack', array($newShipmentId, $shippedby, $shipname, $fields[4]));
            }
            catch (Exception $e) { echo 'Shipment creation failed on order '. $ShippedOrderId . ': ', $e->getMessage(); }


            // Add comment to order with all the info
             $client->call($sess_id, 'sales_order.addComment', array($ShippedOrderId, 'complete',  $comment,  false));
            $mail_content .= $line . "\n";
            $importcount++;
         }
      //}
   }
```

Edit 2/25/13

---

Using below implementation. I have error from running this script. I haven't been able to test it though since I would have to when the cron runs at 5am.

```
// Make shipment and add tracking number
            if ($fields[3] == 'UPS-RESIDENTIAL') { $shippedby = 'ups'; $shipname = 'UPS Ground'; }
            elseif ($fields[3] == 'UPS-2') { $shippedby = 'ups'; $shipname = 'UPS 2nd Day Air'; }
            elseif ($fields[3] == 'UPS-OVERNIGHT') { $shippedby = 'ups'; $shipname = 'UPS Next Day Air Saver'; }
            elseif ($fields[3] == 'USPS-PRI') { $shippedby = 'usps'; $shipname = 'USPS Priority'; }
            elseif ($fields[3] == 'CANADA') { $shippedby = 'custom'; $shipname = 'MSI Canada (Standard) '; }
            elseif ($fields[3] == 'MSITRACK') { $shippedby = 'custom'; $shipname = 'MSI Canada (Express)'; }
            else { $shippedby = 'custom'; }


        /////////////////////////////////////////////       
        $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($orderId);

        $shipment_collection = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_shipment_collection');
        $shipment_collection->addAttributeToFilter('order_id', $orderId);
        $shipment_collection->load();

        $firstItem = $shipment_collection->getFirstItem();

        if(count($shipment_collection) > 1)
        {

            $track_no = $fields[4]; // insert tracking # string here

                $shipment = Mage::getModel('sales/order_shipment');
                $shipment->load($firstItem->getId());
                if($shipment->getId() != '')
                {
                    $track = Mage::getModel('sales/order_shipment_track')
                        ->setShipment($shipment)
                        ->setData('title', $shipname) // User syntax correct name here
                        ->setData('number', $track_no)
                        ->setData('carrier_code', $shippedby) // use code that matches DB code for ship method here
                        ->setData('order_id', $shipment->getData('order_id'));

                    $track->save();
                }

            return true;

        } else {

            $orderShip = $order->prepareShipment(); // can take sku => qty array
            $orderShip->register();
            $orderShip->sendEmail();

            $tracker = Mage::getModel( 'sales/order_shipment_track' );
            $tracker->setShipment( $orderShip );
            $tracker->setData( 'title', $shipname );
            $tracker->setData( 'number', $importData['Tracking Number'] );
            $tracker->setData( 'carrier_code', $shippedby );
            $tracker->setData( 'order_id', $orderId );

            $orderShip->addTrack($tracker);
            $orderShip->save();

            $order->setData('state', "complete");
            $order->setStatus("complete");
                $history = $order->addStatusHistoryComment('Order marked as complete by shipment code.', false);
                $history->setIsCustomerNotified(false);
            $order->save(); 
            /////////////////////////////////////////////////








            // Add comment to order with all the info
             $client->call($sess_id, 'sales_order.addComment', array($ShippedOrderId, 'complete',  $comment,  false));
            $mail_content .= $line . "\n";
            $importcount++;
         }
      //}
   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would strip out the use of the API all together.

Try this:

```
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($orderId);

        $shipment_collection = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_shipment_collection');
        $shipment_collection->addAttributeToFilter('order_id', $orderId);
        $shipment_collection->load();

        $firstItem = $shipment_collection->getFirstItem();

        if(count($shipment_collection) > 1)
        {

            $track_no = "FEDEX9879879"; // insert tracking # string here

                $shipment = Mage::getModel('sales/order_shipment');
                $shipment->load($firstItem->getId());
                if($shipment->getId() != '')
                {
                    $track = Mage::getModel('sales/order_shipment_track')
                        ->setShipment($shipment)
                        ->setData('title', 'United Parcel Service') // User syntax correct name here
                        ->setData('number', $track_no)
                        ->setData('carrier_code', 'ups') // use code that matches DB code for ship method here
                        ->setData('order_id', $shipment->getData('order_id'));

                    $track->save();
                }

            return true;

        } else {

            $orderShip = $order->prepareShipment(); // can take sku => qty array
            $orderShip->register();
            $orderShip->sendEmail();

            $tracker = Mage::getModel( 'sales/order_shipment_track' );
            $tracker->setShipment( $orderShip );
            $tracker->setData( 'title', 'United Parcel Service' );
            $tracker->setData( 'number', $importData['Tracking Number'] );
            $tracker->setData( 'carrier_code', 'ups' );
            $tracker->setData( 'order_id', $orderId );

            $orderShip->addTrack($tracker);
            $orderShip->save();

            $order->setData('state', "complete");
            $order->setStatus("complete");
                $history = $order->addStatusHistoryComment('Order marked as complete by shipment code.', false);
                $history->setIsCustomerNotified(false);
            $order->save();
```

Notice the saving of orderShip automatically saves the tracker, and you CAN NOT save a tracker object on its own because it will fail foreign key constraint.

Comment: I took out the try and catch and put what I have above (see my edit) and the cron did not run that night. Do you see any error?

Comment: Try manually running it from shell to debug. Sometimes Magento's built in cron doesn't run as expected.

Comment: I do see errors I your implementation, some of the variables need to be replaced with whatever your data is. Particularly where the actual tracking number is injected.

Comment: Yeah thats the only variable I see that I implemented wrong. I replaced that with $fields[4] which is defined. Is tere anything else I'm supposed to add to the top!?

Comment: I'm getting Fatal error: Class 'Mage' not found in /home/ab71714/public_html/exporter/importer-sftp.php on line 204 which is $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($orderId);

Comment: Trying require "/home/ab71714/public_html/app/Mage.php";
//umask(0);
Mage::app();
 Mage::getSingleton('core/session', array('name'=>'frontend'));

Comment: Fatal error: Call to a member function getMethodInstance() on a non-object in /home/ab71714/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Payment/Helper/Data.php on line 119 error on this line " $orderShip->sendEmail();"

Answer (score 3):

The above implementation almost worked for me but I was unable to add the tracking numbers. I eventually went back to testing out the code from the Magento soap API. The following also added the tracking numbers:

```
 try { 
            // Create new shipment
            $newShipmentId = $client->call($sess_id, 'sales_order_shipment.create', array($ShippedOrderId, array(), 'Shipment Created', true, true));
            $newTrackId = $client->call($sess_id, 'sales_order_shipment.addTrack', array($newShipmentId, $shippedby, $shipname, $fields[4]));
            }
            catch (Exception $e) { echo 'Shipment creation failed on order '. $ShippedOrderId . ': ', $e->getMessage(); }
```

Can't believe I spent so much time on it because I had tried this before and I think I just messed up a variable. Happy to help anyone who may need extra assistance.