# Can the Magento soap api add a tracking order after the shipment was already created?

Tags: php, magento, soap

I have the code below and the orders have already had a shipment created, but I am trying to add the tracking number. Can the tracking number be added via this method if the shipment was already created and order marked complete?

```
$newShipmentId = $client->call($sess_id, 'sales_order_shipment.create', array($ShippedOrderId, array(), 'Shipment Created', true, true));
            $newTrackId = $client->call($sess_id, 'sales_order_shipment.addTrack', array($newShipmentId, $shippedby, $shipname, $fields[4]));}
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems you cannot add tracking number after shipment is created via this method. View my answer at [Magento SOAP API sales_order_shipment create and addTrack questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994809/magento-soap-api-sales-order-shipment-create-and-addtrack-questions)